# Calling ascx.cs method from ascx page using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a code behind file which contains a method:

public string ProductsAsJson()

which returns a json representation of a series of products. I want to be able to use some angular functions in my ascx page and so I am trying to call the function using:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   var products = <%# ProductsAsJson() %>;
```

but it is failing to retrieve the list of products.

What am I a doing wrong?

Comment: thanks but I get the following error when I do this:
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: I got into this situation sometimes ago, does not remember clearly but i think keep the syntax same (var products = <%# ProductsAsJson() %>;)  and move your JS into body instead of head. Can't try it right now but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the return value of ProductsAsJson() in a public variable and call this method on page load in .cs and access the value of variable in ascx control and assign to javascript variable.

```
var products = <%# ProductsAsJson %>;
```